# How to handle javascript library version changes with grunt-bower-task?

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm using grunt + bower + [grunt-bower-task](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task) plugin to manage javascript library dependencies.

Say I have installed `jquery` with bower:

```
bower install jquery --save
```

and with grunt-bower-task:

```
bower: {
  install: {
    options: {
      targetDir: './public/lib',
      layout: 'byComponent',
      install: true,
      verbose: true,
      cleanTargetDir: true,
      cleanBowerDir: false,
      bowerOptions: {}
    }
  }
}
```

After running `grunt bower`, jquery will be copied to:

```
/public/lib/jquery/jquery.js
```

So the client will fetch jquery with url:

```
http://somedomain.com/public/lib/jquery/jquery.js
```

But I have question, what if I changed the jquery version?

Say I used another query version with bower, but it will still be copied to the same location and user will fetch it with the same url. If I have add cache-headers for it, user won't fetch new jquery.js code from server before expired.

How to fix this problem?

I think if we can add the version to the file name when running `grunt bower`, that will fix it, e.g.

```
http://somedomain.com/public/lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.js
```

But I can't find such functions in `grunt-bower-task`.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle library versioning in the bower.json file. Yours should have the versions to be installed whenever you call the `bower install` command.. something like this

```
 "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.21",
    "jquery": ">=2.1.1"
 },  
 "resolutions": {
   "jquery": ">=2.1.1"
 }
```

But now they're all jquery.js regardless of the version. So now what you'd want to do is add some type of cache busting strategy which will force the browser to download the newest version of your scripts. There's tons of resource on cache busting javascript online, so I won't reiterate those here, but there are grunt tasks that can help you like [this one](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cache-busting)

One slightly off topic suggestion I would make is to concat and minify your externals scripts into one js file and maybe another for your application scripts. As one or more of your external library change, the cache busting technique will force the browser to grab the latest version of your dependent scripts.